# Trying to convert this BASH code into PHP code but faced some problem

Tags: php

I have a problem that I want to solve.

I have this code BASH

```js
get_customer_url() {
  local IP=${1:-127.0.0.1}
  local SECRET=${2:-VERY_COOL_SECRET}
  local EXPIRES="$(date -d "today + 30 minutes" +%s)";
  local token="$(echo -n "${EXPIRES} ${IP} ${SECRET}" | openssl md5 -binary | openssl base64 | tr +/ -_ | tr -d =)"
  echo "https://example.com/video/hls/${token}/${EXPIRES}/live.m3u8"
}
```

And I'm wanting to do this same code but in php. I'm practically trying to do it but in the encryption part with md5 and base64 I'm missing out. I have managed to make it print but it is not equal to the result of the BASH script

This is the php code I can do

```js
<?php

$ip = '127.0.0.1';
$secret = 'VERY_COOL_SECRET';
$expires = time()+30*60;
$token1 = md5("$expires $ip $secret");
$token1 = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($token1), '+/', '-_'), '='); 
echo $token1 ;
```

It returns a string similar to this NTJjNzg4YThlMzA5ZjhjZTjjMDM3YzdkYTE1M2YzMTQ but with the BASH it remains thus Z35QX0iDntGvUD8GYbzxuw. Anyone who can convert this code to php or help me with the code?

Comment: I don't know how that BASH runs but maybe there should be no spaces? `md5($expires . $ip . $secret);` What does `echo -n "${EXPIRES} ${IP} ${SECRET}"` come out as?

Comment: Literally nothing in that code counts as encryption.